# How to compile a c program with two txt files as command line arguments?

Tags: c

```
int fd1, fd2[2], i, tmp;
char c;
int offset, n;
fd1 = open(argv[1], 0400);
fd2[0] = mkdir("~/Assignment", S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); 
fd2[1] = creat(argv[2], 0670);
pipe(fd2);

offset = lseek(fd1, (off_t)0, SEEK_END);

for(i = offset-1; i>=0; i--)
{
    lseek(fd1, (off_t) i, SEEK_SET);

    n = read(fd1, &c, 1);

    n = write(fd2[1], &c, 1);
}
```

I need to open a new directory, and hence a new file and copy the content of file1 into the new file in reverse order. When I'm taking the file name as argument from the command line. Two things happened:

1. At first it didn't recognise the file format and threw me this error :
   file format not recognized; treating as linker script
2. Next I added the flag "-o" and then tried compiling, now there is no a.out file that I can execute.

How should I compile my program with two .txt files as arguments in command line?

Edit : I could solve it finally. I was giving the arguments at the compile time. It works fine when you give it during run time. i.e like : ./a.out txt1 txt2

Comment: Giving arguments in the command line has nothing to do with compilation. When you want to run it, you give the arguments. `./prog arg1 arg2`

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, but when I'm compiling it as $gcc prog.c arg1 arg2
it says that the file format is not recognised.

Comment: Do you included path to text files?

Comment: also when I'm trying to compile it your way. it says - ./prog : command not found

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. It throws me this errror : /usr/bin/ld: error in ./file1.txt(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
@FilipKočica

Comment: I don't believe GCC can compile in your text files. I think you need to just compile with "gcc -o my_prog prog.c" and then need to figure out a way to read in the text files in your c program. That is to do what Tony suggested and add some logic into your main to read the argv/argc and allow the text files to be arguments to your program executable.

Answer (score 1):

You have written that you are compiling like this

```
gcc prog.c arg1 arg2
```

But first you have to compile `.c` to `binary` and then pass args to that created binary.

**Example**

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c prog.c -o prog
./prog arg1 arg2
```

Comment: tried this too, doesn't seem to work, it says : bash: ./test: Permission denied
also doesn't work with sudo :/

Comment: But this isnt about compiling error yet. Its permission problem. Try this `chmod u+x program_name` in your case `chmod u+x test`.

Comment: new error : bash: ./test: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
@Filip

Comment: Yes I did. Sorry I should have closed this question. @Filip

Comment: Just select the answer that helped by placing the green check mark over the number. Also, you may find passing the standard `-std=gnu99` or `-std=gnu11` to benefit from the Gnu extensions (unless you need to comply with a strict `c99` or `c11` standard)

Comment: You shouldn't close answered Q's cuz somebody could have same problem once, but its your decision :-)